# Intellij spring boot PropertiesLauncher

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have spring boot application (1.3.5.RELEASE) which is packaged as a jar file and i would like to have the jdbc drivers in an external libs folder. So i am using the PropertiesLauncher which searches for external jar files.

It works fine when using `java -jar -Dloader.path=lib/` but is does not work inside the Intellij IDE. Its a Maven project which is imported into Intellij.

Any hints for me?

Comment: How are you launching your app in your IDE?

Comment: I have a run configuration for it. The `loader.path` parameter is present in the application.properties file and is also set as VM option. It is starting the main class in my project.

Comment: When you say "the main class" do you mean your application's main class or `PropertiesLauncher`?

Comment: Yes, i mean my own class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `PropertiesLauncher` it sets up a class loader with the contents of the configured `loader.path` and then uses this class loader to load and call your application's main class. When you launch your application's main class directly in your IDE, `PropertiesLauncher` isn't involved so the `loader.path` system property has no effect.

It is possible to use `PropertiesLauncher` in your IDE but it'll require a bit of extra configuration. You'll need to configure a run configuration that has `spring-boot-loader` and your application on the classpath that launches `PropertiesLauncher`. You can then use the `loader.main` system property to tell `PropertiesLauncher` the name of your application's main class.

Answer (score 6):

Following the answer of Andy I thought I will post how I did resolved it:

1. I've added a profile for the dependency

   ```
   <profile>
       <id>intellij-properties-launcher</id>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

   </profile>
   ```
2. I activated the profile on Intellij on the maven tab

   [image: Activation on IDE]
3. Changed the configuration according to andy
   [image: Run Configuration]

NOTE: Intellij Ultimate 2018.3. It will mark the Configuration as Invalid, but it works :)

I hope to help someone.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer, it helps me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am able to add my application.properties this way (my spring profiles are now loaded which are specified in my application.properties outside the jar), but I'm not able to open any other resources. For example, I have a x-something.properties file also located in the loader.path but that's not added to the classpath. Any idea how to fix that?